# Check Symbol(✓) doesn't display in PDF using jasper report

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I developed a report in jasper wherein it displays a check symbol(✓) for existing records (i.e. list of requirements). 
It seems like I would never had a problem displaying it since the check symbol is visible during preview in the iReport. But once I viewed the report in PDF format, the check symbol is no longer visible. I even tried unicode characters instead of the check image, even unicode for square root.

What configuration am I missing here?

Comment: Ah, font problems in PDF generation. I have no solution, but much commiseration. (You might want to check for similar issues in postscript generation; this is an area where there are many similarities IIRC.)

Comment: You said you "even tried" other unicode characters... but you don't say if they worked or not :V

Comment: What font did you use in report?

Answer (score 1):

Embedding the font in the report might solve your issue. This article discusses how to embed fonts using iReport and not using it: [Embedding fonts into PDF generated by JasperReports](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.com/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to add image of (check-mark) and build

To create parameter paramImage and set  the image expression property as $P{paramImage}.

To passing value to this variable as

```
String imagePath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/images/IMAGE.jpg");
```

Then put parameters as given below

```
paramaters.put("paramImage",imagePath);
```